# How to randomize pixels in image/movie (size 12x12 pixels)

Tags: uv, compositing-nodes, texture-coordinates

I have 1920x1080 pixels movie. For some education purposes I have to demonstrate what it's going to look like if it would be

1) 12x12 pixels movie, and

2) when the pixels of that 12x12 movie would be randomly mixed up. (I don't need to mix them up continuously during playback, just once done than to be used).

Item one is done and I have a footage where I have 12x12 rectangles movie with a certain monochrome color each (lets call rectangles pseudo pixels, or PP). But I don't have an idea how to mix up the PP. So far I only think of creating 144 planes, than assign each of the plane the color of a particular PP in UV editor and than manually put the planes next to one another 12 rows 12 columns. 
But I wonder, if there's a better (easier) way to do that? I think it's possible to do with compositing but I'm not good in that.

Comment: You can create spritesheet from all images outside Blender, there are some online services or photoshop plugins. There is even spritesheet addon for 2.7x https://www.moddb.com/engines/blender-game-engine/downloads/sprite-sheet-addon-for-blender-vse

Comment: Serge, unfortunately it's not what I need. Two reasons. 1) it's not random, 2) it's not for movie (unless you do it all manually frame by frame), 3) the tiles in this plugin are frames, in my case it's a segment of a frame (144 tiles in each frame).

Comment: And reason. 3)  the tiles in this plugin are frames, in my case it's a segment of a frame (144 tiles in each frame).

Yet the plugin can be helpful for other purposes and it's good that now I know about this technics. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Tile Randomizer**

[image]

How does it work? Faces of one plane (tiles) are mapped through *Explode* modifier to randomized faces of a plane with *Build* modifier.

1. Create a *Plane* and UV unwrap it, then loopcut it or subdivide to match desired columns and rows amount (final facecount = rows * columns). This is *Randomizer* object
2. Duplicate *Plane* <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> and add material with image. This is *Image Plane* object
3. Add *Build modifier* to *Randomizer*, check *Randomize* and drive a seed with expression `#frame`. May add *Stepped interpolation* modifier for a driver to control time interval before switching seed (step size is 5 for GIF in example).
4. Add *Particle System* to *Randomizer*, set particle count to match facecount, enable modifiers stack and set particle/face ratio to 1, also choose *Keyed* physics.
5. Add *Particle System* to *Image Plane*, and link same particles set as for *Randomizer*. In *Physics* tab press "+" button and add *Randomizer*'s particle system as a target key.
6. Add *Explode modifier* to *Image Plane*.

Test file done in **2.79** for Blender Internal engine.

[image]

Comment: Serge, I'm amazed how people can be so creative!
I even don't understand all of what you wrote but I'm pretty sure I'will manage it when trying to repeat since you also had provided the file! Thanks a lot.
I even think you went further than I asked. If I understand it correct it keeps changing tiles (randomly) when playing back. While I only asked mix up tiles once and than play video the same tile layout all the way to the end. And I hope that the version I need will work without particles. But I have to try it.
Thanks a lot, I'll let know how it will work.

Comment: Yes, you get it right, just don't animate *seed* parameter in Build modifier and it will freeze randomization for whole timeline. Particles are crucial for this setup, otherwise it won't work I guess.

Comment: Serge, it DOES work! I don't understand how, but it works.
Thank you a LOT!!!